# Re-structing Data in R studio

Tags: r, reshape, transformation

I'm relatively new to R and want to restructure my data which currently looks like this:

```
sample <- data.frame("num" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
sample$CustomerID <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)
sample$product <- c("Eggs", "Bread", "Coke", "Coke", "Eggs", "Apples", "Bread", "Cookies", "Coke", "Milk")
sample$quantity <- c(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1)
```

| customerID | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eggs | 1 |
| 2 | Bread | 1 |
| 2 | Coke | 3 |
| 3 | Coke | 2 |
| 3 | Eggs | 2 |

Want it to look like this:

| customerID | Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 | Prod4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eggs |  |  |  |
| 2 | Bread | Coke | Coke | Coke |
| 3 | Coke | Coke | Eggs | Eggs |

Tried Reshape() but I dont think I completely understand how that works.

Answer (score 1):

One option using `dplyr` and `tidyr` may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)

sample %>%
  select(-num) %>% 
  tidyr::uncount(quantity) %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID) %>% 
  mutate(prod_id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = prod_id, values_from = product, names_prefix = "prod")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>   CustomerID prod1  prod2 prod3 prod4   prod5 prod6 prod7
#>        <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1          1 Eggs   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2          2 Bread  Coke  Coke  Coke    <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3          3 Coke   Coke  Eggs  Eggs    <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4          4 Apples Bread Bread Cookies Coke  Coke  Coke 
#> 5          5 Milk   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: How and which logic did you encountered behind the scenes?

Comment: @Tarjae Lol. Yeah. Needed a second glance to understand what the OP is trying to achieve. For example Customer 2 buys one bread and 3 coke, hence the first product he/she buys is a bread while product 2, 3 and 4 are a coke. That's why I first uncount and add the product id's